# How to add multiple submit buttons in ACF form?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using  ACF Form in Front-end of a WordPress website. It is used to create a custom posts in WordPress. I need to add two submit buttons in this ACF Form. when i click the first button, it should create a new post and post status should be publish and when I click the another button, it should create a new post and post status should be draft.

My code below  will create a post with status as published. How can i achieve this?

```
<?php
acf_form(array(
'post_id'       => 'new_post',
'field_groups' => array(258),
'new_post'      => array(
'post_type'     => 'property',
),
'post_title' => true,
'post_title_label'  => 'Community Name',
'submit_value'  => 'Submit for Review'
)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible achieve this using the hidden field and a bit of jQuery.

Step 1: You need to add the hidden field and set default value as 1.

```
<?php

acf_form_head();
acf_form(array(
'post_id' => 'new_post',
'field_groups' => array(258),
'new_post' => array(
'post_type' => 'property',
),
'id' => 'form_draft',
'html_after_fields' => '<input type="hidden" id="hiddenId" name="acf[current_step]" value="1"/>',
'return' => home_url('property-thank-you'),
'post_title' => true,
'post_title_label' => 'Community Name',
'submit_value' => 'Publish'
)
);
?>
```

Step 2:

Use the below code near the form and then append this field to the form using jQuery.

```
<input type="submit" id="draft_btn" class="acf-button2 button button-primary button-large" name="draft_btn" value="Save as Draft" onclick="click_ignore();">

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#draft_btn").detach().appendTo('.acf-form-submit');
});
</script>
```

Step 3: When Clicking on the "Draft" button overwrite its value as 2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function click_ignore(e) {
document.getElementById('hiddenId').value = 2;
return false;
}
</script>
```

Step 4: Add the below code in fucntions.php which will change the post status based on the button which we click.

```
<?php
function my_acf_save_post($post_id) {

$submitedStatus = $_POST['acf']['current_step'];
if ($submitedStatus == 1){
$value = 'pending';
}else if ($submitedStatus == 2){
$value = 'draft';
}

// Update current post
$my_post = array(
'ID' => $post_id,
'post_status' => $value,
);
remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post($my_post);

// Add the action back
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
}

// run after ACF saves the $_POST['acf'] data
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
?>
```

We have added both the 'Publish' and 'Save as Draft' buttons in a single ACF form.

Comment: Thank you Murali it's very useful in my project. Now i fix the issue